# Passar variavel php em função javascript

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Poderiam me ajudar com uma dúvida?
Preciso passar valores de variáveis PHP para uma função JavaScript (Laravel).

```php
//+5%
$tv90 = number_format($tv90 + ($tv90/100*5), 2, '.', '');
$tv125 = number_format($tv125 + ($tv125/100*5), 2, '.', '');
$tc50 = number_format($tc50 + ($tc50/100*5), 2, '.', '');
$ts100 = number_format($ts100 + ($ts100/100*5), 2, '.', '');
$ts150 = number_format($ts150 + ($ts150/100*5), 2, '.', '');
$tcomp = number_format($tcomp + ($tcomp/100*5), 2, '.', '');
```

```js
function drawChart() { 
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Mês', 'DC', 'FUNDIÇÃO', 'BRITAGEM', 'BORRACHA', 'NELES', 'REFORMA'],
    ['JAN', 300, 400, 200, 1000, 400, 200]]);}

    $(window).resize(function () { drawChart();
});
```

Quero substituir os valores por variaveis, carregar dinamicamente.

Answer (score -3):

É importante saber que o PHP roda no servidor, e devolve HTML. O JavaScript pode ser escrito dentro de tags HTML. Portanto para passar um valor do PHP para o JavaScript é só fazer:

```php
<?php
$valorNoPHP = 'meu valor veio do PHP';
?>
<script>
var variavelJavaScriptComValorDoPHP = '<?= $valorNoPHP ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

O exemplo abaixo mostra uma estrutura de classe em JavaScript que recebe uma variável PHP como parâmetro e a encaminha para o construtor da classe. Isso permite que você utilize a variável PHP no código JavaScript usando programação orientada a objetos, inclusive em um arquivo externo .js. Se o código ficar um pouco complexo, você pode estudar mais sobre o uso de classes em JavaScript no link da Mozilla a seguir: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes.

**PHP:**

```
$jsVars = json_encode([
  'tv90' => number_format($tv90 + ($tv90/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'tv125' => number_format($tv125 + ($tv125/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'tc50' => number_format($tc50 + ($tc50/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'ts100' => number_format($ts100 + ($ts100/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'ts150' => number_format($ts150 + ($ts150/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'tcomp' => number_format($tcomp + ($tcomp/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
]);
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
class FormValidation {
  constructor(jsVars) {
    this.phpVars = jsVars;
  }

  drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Mês', 'DC', 'FUNDIÇÃO', 'BRITAGEM', 'BORRACHA', 'NELES', 'REFORMA'],
      ['JAN', this.phpVars.tv90, this.phpVars.tv125, this.phpVars.tc50, this.phpVars.ts100, this.phpVars.ts150, this.phpVars.tcomp],
    ]);

  }
}

const formValidation = new FormValidation(<?php echo $jsVars ?>);

$(document).ready(function() {
  formValidation.drawChart();
});
```

**Explicando o código:**

1. Primeiro, é criado um objeto JSON com as variáveis PHP utilizando a função json_encode().
2. Em seguida, é definida a classe FormValidation com um construtor que recebe o objeto JSON como parâmetro e armazena as variáveis PHP na propriedade this.phpVars.
3. A classe também tem uma função drawChart() que desenha um gráfico utilizando os valores das variáveis PHP armazenados na propriedade this.phpVars.
4. A classe é instanciada passando o objeto JSON como parâmetro para o construtor.
5. Quando a página é carregada, a função drawChart() é chamada para desenhar o gráfico com os valores das variáveis PHP.

**Alternativamente**, se preferir uma implementação mais simples e sem o uso de programação orientada a objetos, você pode criar um objeto JSON com as variáveis PHP e passá-lo como parâmetro para a função JavaScript. Em seguida, você pode acessar as propriedades do objeto JSON na função e utilizar os valores das variáveis PHP dinamicamente.

```
<?php
// Criando um objeto JSON com as variáveis PHP
$phpVars = json_encode([
  'tv90' => number_format($tv90 + ($tv90/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'tv125' => number_format($tv125 + ($tv125/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'tc50' => number_format($tc50 + ($tc50/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'ts100' => number_format($ts100 + ($ts100/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'ts150' => number_format($ts150 + ($ts150/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
  'tcomp' => number_format($tcomp + ($tcomp/100*5), 2, '.', ''),
]);
?>

<!-- Passando o objeto JSON para a função JavaScript -->
<script>
function drawChart(phpVars) { 
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Mês', 'DC', 'FUNDIÇÃO', 'BRITAGEM', 'BORRACHA', 'NELES', 'REFORMA'],
    ['JAN', phpVars.tv90, phpVars.tv125, phpVars.tc50, phpVars.ts100, phpVars.ts150, phpVars.tcomp],
  ]);
}

$(window).resize(function () {
  drawChart(<?php echo $phpVars ?>); // Chamando a função e passando o objeto JSON como parâmetro
});
</script>
```